# Insert only unique values into db table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm using `vinkla/instagram` composer package in my Laravel to fetch Instagram posts in my app.

Since Instagram allows the package to call their API 200 times per hour I'm trying to save post links into database table. And this package fetches 20 latest posts and its attributes.

Here I'm trying to compare the link of posts fetched by `vinkla/instagram` composer package and already saved posts and insert only unique into to table.
Below is the code snippet:

```
    $instagram = new Instagram('access-token');
    $posts = $instagram->media(); //gets 20 latest insta posts of a user
    $fromDBs = Insta::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(20)->get(); //get last 20 rows from table
    foreach( $posts as $post)
    {
        foreach( $fromDBs as $fromDB)
        {
            if($post->images->low_resolution->url != $fromDB->link)
            {
                $create = new Insta;
                $create->link =  $post->images->low_resolution->url;
                $create->save();
            }               
        }
    }
```

With the above stated code the new links are inserted `x10` times.
What would be the correct way to insert unique link once only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are `firstOrCreate` or `firstOrNew` helper functions on [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent), so you can create it only if it does not exist in order to prevent duplicates. So instead of your check you can check this code:

```
foreach( $posts as $post)
{
    Insta::firstOrCreate(['link' => $post->images->low_resolution->url]);
}
```

Comment: Laravel beauty.

Answer (score 1):

```
...
foreach( $posts as $post)
{
    foreach( $fromDBs as $fromDB)
    {
        if($post->images->low_resolution->url != $fromDB->link)
        {
            $create = Insta::firstOrNew(['link' => $post->images->low_resolution->url]);

           if(! $create->id ) $create->save();
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: @nakov's solution is better